# Regex for only letters and numbers but no numbers at the beginning or end

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I want to make a regex that matches only letters and numbers, but no numbers at the beginning or the end:

- `ahmed0saber` is *valid*
- `0ahmedsaber` is *not valid*
- `ahmedsaber0` is *not valid*
- `ahmed_saber` is *not valid*

I tried this

```
[a-z0-9_]
```

but it doesn't work as expected!

Comment: `/^[a-z](?:[a-z\d]*[a-z])?$/i`

Comment: Is `a` a valid input?

Answer (score 2):

This should work `^[a-z][a-z\d]*[a-z]$`

```js
const regex = /^[a-z][a-z\d]*[a-z]$/
const tests = ['ahmed0saber', '0ahmedsaber', 'ahmedsaber0', 'ahmed_saber']
tests.forEach(test)

function test(name) {
  console.log(name, name.match(regex) ? 'yes' : 'no')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you also want to allow a single character:

```
 ^[a-z](?![a-z\d]*\d$)[a-z\d]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z]` Match a single char a-z
- `(?![a-z\d]*\d$)` Negative lookahead, assert the the string does not end on a digit
- `[a-z\d]*` Match optional chars a-z or digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pvaTN5/1).

Or if a lookbehind assertion is supported:

```
^[a-z][a-z\d]*$(?<!\d)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-z]` Match a single char a-z
- `[a-z\d]*` Match optional chars a-z or digits
- `$` End of string
- `(?<!\d)` Negative lookabehind, assert not a digit at the end

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/31HqXv/1).